# Redirect site.com URL to external URL

Tags: community, community-builder, site.com

I have a site.com URL as **`https://xxx.force.com/s`**.  Need to redirect the Url to **`Google.com.`**

Under Sites--> URL Redirect --> I defined the Source URL and Target URL and made it active , but **`https://xxx.force.com/s`** is not directing to **`External URL.`**

I created a VF page with Pagereference to re-direct to Google.com and replaced the Site Active Home page with Customized VF pAGE , but this VF page Redirect is only working When URL is **`https://xxx.force.com/`** but not **`https://xxx.force.com/s`**.

Is it possible to redirect the Url ending with **`https://xxx.force.com/s`** to **`Google.com`**?